Validity of disease duration variable in survival analysis
I am wondering about the validity of including a 'disease duration' variable in a cox model, when the disease duration is measured from the start of observation (i.e. at the point of diagnosis)?
This doesn't really make sense to include, does it, as this variable and observation time would essentially be collinear?
edit: The index date in this case is the diagnosis date and we are interested in looking at time to progression (defined by a relapse after a period of relative stability) of the disease. There is no chance for recovery/cure.
I am also thinking about how this would make sense to parameterise, anyway. You can't just use disease duration measured from the start to end of observation (either determined by an event of censoring) because that brings 'looking into the future' issues with your covariate values, as the Cox model uses current covariate values at failure times. So then how would you define this? - convert it to a time-varying covariate based on splitting time at all failures (as the Cox model estimates the partial likelihood at the failure times)? If I'm thinking about things correctly, wouldn't that then lead to completely collinear covariate values and observation times? Does that matter, and if it doesn't, is it informative anyway?
Perhaps I am overthinking things
Thanks @EdM and @PBulls

What is your study design? An experimental intervention is rarely introduced at a fixed time post diagnosis, and the disease duration may well be prognostic for the ability of that intervention to change time until event. If your index date is the diagnosis then that's a different situation.

In addition to the definition of the time = 0 reference raised in another comment, the nature of the disease/death process also matters. Is the "disease duration" time from diagnosis to death or time from diagnosis to recovery? Are recovery and death competing risks? Please edit the question to provide those details, which are important for formulating and answer, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

It seems that there is no difference between "disease duration" and the time between diagnosis and relapse:

disease duration is measured from the start of observation (i.e. at the point of diagnosis)


we are interested in looking at time to progression (defined by a relapse after a period of relative stability) of the disease. There is no chance for recovery/cure.

If that's the situation, then you are correct that you can't include "disease duration" as a predictor, as it's the same as (not just collinear with) the outcome (time to progression) that you are trying to model.
